# Display control only if not viewing remotely

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to show a control on a page ONLY if the page was requested over the local network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use [`Request.IsLocal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx) property, it gets a value indicating whether the request is from the local computer. E.g.

```
theControl.Visible = Request.IsLocal;
```

**EDIT:** the answer I provided above is works for a local host only:

To fully answer your question, the subnet mask for the network should be known.
You also may use IP address extension methods from here: [IP Address Calculations with C# (Subnetmasks, Networks, …)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2008/12/31/ip-address-calculations-with-c-subnetmasks-networks.aspx) and use it like:

```
var ip1 = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1");
var ip2 = IPAddress.Parse(Request.UserHostAddress);
var mask = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0");
bool inSameNet = ip1.IsInSameSubnet(ip2, mask);
```

To get the the user host address you could use [`HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) method; but remember host address **can be spoofed**.

Comment: When you say "for a local host only", do you mean only localhost (127.0.0.1) or the the IP for the machine I'm requesting it from? The site that I would be using this on is bound to a specific local IP, and is not listening to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Ah. I just RTFM from your link. It should work for a local IP, not just 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Jeremy, yes this should work for the *local server*. But be careful if your host has multiple IP addresses configured. In that case I suggets to look onto [Dns.GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx) method.

Comment: What is the danger? I do have multiple IP addresses configured, but they're all on the local network.

Comment: @Jeremy, it seems I misinform you. Some time ago I read something about multiple IP addresses and `.IsLocal` property issue, but I cannot recollect where. And I just configured my PC to have multiple IP addresses, then configured my website bindings in IIS to have multiple IP addresses. The `.IsLocal` property returned `true` for every IP I configure. One more sorry.

Comment: Is it possible to bypass this check with IP spoofing?

Comment: @Jeremy, didn't try it out by myself, but think this is completely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy.

You can get the current request's ip using `HttpContext.Current.UserHostAddress` see [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx).  How you compare that to your local subnet(s) is up to you.  You can then set the visibility property on your control accordingly.